# Accessing the array values of dropdownbox using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select size="6" name="operator[]" id="operator[]" size="5" multiple="">
    <option value="1" >One</option>
    <option value="2" >Two</option>
    ....
    ....
    <option value="10" >Ten</option>
</select>
```

My question now is how can I access the array values of dropdownbox using jquery?

```
$("#operator").val(); // Not working
$("#operator[]").val(); // Not working as well
```

Comment: Anyway to avoid using `[]` in ID ???

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid `id` and `name` property, use this code:

```
$("#operator").find('option:selected').each(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

demo: [jsfiddle.net/VYjEM/](http://jsfiddle.net/VYjEM/)

Comment: More data: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select[name='operator[]']").val();
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/eqoyes/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `$("select").val()` will give you the *values* of the *selected* options. If you want to get hold of *all* the options, use `$("select > option")`.

Also: using the characters `[]` in the id attribute is [illegal in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and it does not buy you anything particular; you should probably fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to escape the `[` and `]` using `\\`

```
$("#operator\\[\\]").val();
```

or you can use `$("select[id='operator[]']").val()`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fqRcm/)

Answer (score 0):

First things first. I think it is not allowed to use an array for element id. With that being said, set the element id to 'operator' rather than 'operator[]'.

After you've done that, you can get the options in several ways:

1. Using the element dom id:

   ```
   $('#operator option');
   ```
2. Using the element dom type:

   ```
   $('select option');
   ```
3. Using both (recommended):

   ```
   $('select#operator option');
   ```

More information about the selectors jQuery supports can be found at [the official website](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).